# How to make a turn system in JavaScript dice game

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a JS dice game and need help making a turn system (2 or more players)

I've tried to make all kinds of lines of code, but i have no idea how to make it happen

```
var score = 0;



function rollDice() {
    var die1 = document.getElementById("die1");
    var die2 = document.getElementById("die2");
    var status = document.getElementById("status");
    var status2 = document.getElementById("status2");
    var d1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    var d2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    var diceTotal = d1 + d2;
    var totalscore = 0;
    totalscore += diceTotal;
    die1.innerHTML = d1;
    die2.innerHTML = d2;
    status.innerHTML = "You rolled " + diceTotal + ".";
    status2.innerHTML = "Total Points " + totalscore + ".";
  if (d1 == d2) {
     status.innerHTML += " DOUBLES! You get a free turn!!";
  }
  if (diceTotal > 0) {
     status2.innerHTML = score += totalscore;
  }
}
```

Comment: Look at here [link](https://codepen.io/gearmobile/pen/mEJwYw)

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on? It's all about representation. Ideally you'd have a variable that keeps track of whose turn it is. Then you'd need an interface that can talk to your game state representation. Try figuring out how you want it to work on paper before trying to code it.

Comment: Also decide on whether you want both players to use the same dice (on screen). If you need an arbitrary number of players, store their scores in an array (one entry per player), ... etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a players as an array and keep a variable to track of turn. And update the turn variable in the end of roleDice function. Something like the snippet below.

```
var score = 0;
var players = [player1, player2, player3];
var turn = 0;

function rollDice() {

   var currentPlayer = players[turn];

   ....
   ....

   turn++;
   if(turn == players.length) {
      turn = 0;
   }

}
```